# Erro no IF (importando o df com Pandas)

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas

Boa noite.

Estou com o seguinte problema. Toda vez que tento fazer um IF usando um DF, dá esse erro (The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()). Já tentei outros IF's mais simples também porém nunca vai, não sei se tem algo que não estou fazendo ou estou fazendo de errado. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar nisso, agradeço muito.

[Segue print do código e do erro.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsbWk.png)

```
liq_via_v2 = pedidos_liq_via['Valor Líquido do Pedido'] < 0
liq_via_v2 = ((pedidos_liq_via['Soma Desconto na NF'] > pedidos_liq_via['Soma Desconto na DV']) & (pedidos_liq_via['Soma Quantidade na NF'] == pedidos_liq_via['Soma Quantidade na DV'])) & (pedidos_liq_via['Soma Quantidade na DV'] > pedidos_liq_via['Soma Quantidade na NF'])
concat = pd.merge(pedidos_liq_via, liq_via_v2.to_frame(), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
concat = concat.rename(columns={'0': 'Validação'})
concat.info()

if liq_via_v2 == "Verdadeiro":
    pedidos_liq_via['Valor Corrigido'] == 0
else:
    pedidos_liq_via['Valor Corrigido'] == pedidos_liq_via['Valor Líquido do Pedido']
pedidos_liq_via.info()
```

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Caro [@Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/311153/rafael-thomaz), credito que você esteja fazendo testes com seu _datarame_, pois o `concat` está sendo definido e não utilizado.
A variável `lie_via_v2` (na segunda linha) é uma condição. Sendo assim, você pode utilizar:
`pedidos_liq_via.loc[liq_via_v2, 'Valor Corrigido'] = 0` e `pedidos_liq_via.loc[~liq_via_v2, 'Valor Corrigido'] = 0` . O til (`~`) corresponde ao `not`

Answer (score -2):

Olá!

Quando você compara duas Sérias pandas com qualquer operador de comparação, ele vai retornar uma lista de valores booleanos

Por exemplo

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
s2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

s1 == s2 # [True, True, True, True, True]
```

e caso você queira verificar se as duas listas são iguais, basta fazer o seguinte

```
(s1 == s2).all() # True
```